# A joined table into a json with an array field

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

I have two SQL tables that I join -one to many relationship.The query is being requested by a node.JS server of mine and I need parse that information into a JSON that for every repeated row I need to insert the data into an array. or alternatively I could query for the tables separately without a join if it is more convenient for the solution as long as I get the JSON that I need.

I never really tried anything yet because I dont know where to start, I thought about map or reduce functions that could help but map returns the same amount of object to the array and reduce reduces them to one...

lets say the first table is a Person table and gives me a json like so:

```
[
{id:1,name:dani},
{id:2,name:dana},
{id:3,name:dan},
]
```

and the second table has foreign key for that person Id and a dog related to that owner:

```
[
{onwerId:1,dogName:Blacky},
{onwerId:1,dogName:Whitey},
{onwerId:2,dogName:Greeny},
]
```

and if I request the tables left joined together (no need for duplicate onwerId and id) I could get:

```
[
{id:1,name:dani,dogName:Blacky},
{id:1,name:dani,dogName:Whitey},
{id:2,name:dana,dogName:Greeny},
{id:3,name:dan,dogName:NULL},
]
```

the problem is I dont want the dani thing to show up twice.
I want for every identical person id to make a dog array so the result will show like so:

```
[
{id:1,name:dani,dogs:[{dogName:Blacky},{dogName:Whitey}]},
{id:2,name:dana,dogs:[{dogName:Greeny}]},
{id:3,name:dan,dogs:[]}
]
```

as for person id 3 in the example- I dont mind it be NULL instead of an empty array.

Comment: Are you using any ORM's

Answer (score 0):

So you could do something like this

I created two temporary tables to mockup something resembling your test data

```
SELECT 1 Id, 'Dani' Name
INTO #Person
UNION
SELECT 2, 'Dana'
UNION
SELECT 3, 'Dan'

SELECT 1 OwnerId, 'Blacky' DogName
INTO #Dog
UNION
SELECT 1, 'Whitey'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'Greeny'
```

And then create a CTE where the dog names are concatenated into one string

```
;WITH DogGroup AS
(
    --Build dog strings
    SELECT OwnerId, STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + DogName
                FROM #Dog D2
                WHERE D2.OwnerId = D.OwnerId
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') Names
    FROM #Dog D
    GROUP BY
        OwnerId
)
SELECT
    P.Id, P.Name, D.Names
FROM 
    #Person P
JOIN 
    DogGroup D ON P.Id = D.OwnerId
```

Giving you this result

```
Id  Name    Names
1   Dani    Blacky,Whitey
2   Dana    Greeny
```

Comment: I do need the third person to show, even if it has no related rows on the second table